# Using a continuous variable as a label in AutoML Vision

Tags: google-cloud-platform, computer-vision, google-cloud-automl, automl, google-cloud-automl-nl

I would like to know if anyone has had success **labeling images with a continuous variables in the AutoML Vision** platform.

Specifically, I would like to **predict the height of a sand castle from a birds eye view photograph.** I would train the model on birds eye view photographs of sandcastles labeled with the height in inches. I have 10,000 images in my data set. The range of heights in my data set is 1cm to 110cm, so the variable is continuous but not infinite.

Is this achievable through Google AutoML Vision?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As for now, there is no such feature on AutoML Vision that allows you to annotate images using continuous variables. As far as I understand, the labels are treated individually and the model will require "[1000 training images per label. The minimum per label is 10, or 50 for advanced models](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/prepare#preparing_your_images)".

A feasible approach with this would be to use discrete heights or ranges (1cm-20cm, 21cm-50cm, etc).